# tensorflow gives InvalidArgumentError but why?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning about Tensors, and in my exercises I have this example, that's literally the same as this, but mine doesn't work, and I have no clue why?

```
params = tf.constant([
                      [[0, 1.0, 2.0],
                      [10.0, 11.0, 12.0],
                      [20.0, 21.0, 22.0],
                      [30.0, 31.0, 32.0]]
                      ])

print(params.shape)
tf.gather(params, [2, 0], axis = 0)
```

I will get the following output:

```
(1, 4, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-dcd4a927016c> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 
      8 print(params.shape)
----> 9 tf.gather(params, [2, 0], axis = 0)
     10 # axis = 1 is vertical/columns, axis = 0 is horizontal/rows

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58         for t in inputs
     59     ]
---> 60     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     61                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     62   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__GatherV2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} indices[0] = 2 is not in [0, 1) [Op:GatherV2]
```

I don't spot any difference with what the teacher is doing???

But he doesn't get the error.
I'm using Google Colaboratory.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 2nd element isn't available, only element 0 is available, because I forgot to add another tensor element, in the first tensor.